# Figma image download , image quality issue

Tags: html, image, performance, web, figma

I am creating simple html website. I have figma provided for the design. When I export images from **figma** on 1x(png) it's image quality is not good, to get a good quality I have to export them in 2x or 3x which also increases the image size by 2x/3x.

I know I can change the rendered size of the image but big size of the uploaded image is causing to decrease in performance of the website. Can we somehow export images from figma with good quality but of the same size? or any method to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to export some images from your Figma design, for direct use in your website. You want the images to be optimized, so that they load fast, while having that high quality.

1. Make sure you choose the right image format. Use JPG if your image is a photo or contains lots of gradients. -Use PNG if your image is mostly made of flat shapes and colors.
2. Right after you export your Figma images, you can use 3rd party image optimization tools to make them have smaller file sizes.

   There are several ways to do this, like using [Photoshop's Save For Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iY9lnFbq9ng) feature, or by using free online image optimizers, like [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), [Kraken](https://kraken.io/web-interface), [ImageCompressor](https://imagecompressor.com/), [Image Optimizer](http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx), and more.

You can also export your Figma images using image optimizer plugins, such as [OlivePress](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/920429287038206017/Olive-Press---Image-Compression), or [TinyImage Compressor](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/789009980664807964/TinyImage-Compressor). But I haven't tried these, so you have to test for yourself. Just take note that TinyImage is Semi-Free/Semi-Paid.